# SQL - Are there row and column operations in row storage SQL database

Tags: database-theory

I have a very fundamental question.

When one says data is stored in a table, I understand what row-store is,  but are all values in a table stored in contiguous locations? If we are trying to join two tables, are the values in the two tables located in two separate contiguous locations and when we join them, they become one new contiguous location with the required values. Where are the outputs of a sub query held? Is that a separate location too? How is data 'parsed' in a row store?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

Comment: Thanks . It talks about indexes but more fundamentally, where and how is the data stored? Any links would help. I tried searching in multiple ways but was not finding any links.

Comment: One of the motivating purposes for the relational model is to separate how data is accessed from how it is physically stored. There are *very* many different possible representations that are commonly used. Also, there is often no reason to store intermediate results. For example, if I have two sorted tables and I do an equi-join on them, I can just walk over both in parallel returning results to the user as I find them. There are quite a few freely available textbooks that go over the design and implementation of databases, and I would suggest finding one you like and going through it.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thank you. That was helpful.

Comment: @DerekElkins I think you should post that as an answer: although I suspect you posted it as a critique of the question's premise, it's essentially the answer "It's implementation-dependent and here's why."